# Sagemaker Notebook instance error AttributeError: 'MaterializedLayer' object has no attribute 'pack_annotations'

Tags: dask, amazon-sagemaker, dask-distributed, dask-ml, distributed-training

I have a dask cluster active

```
from dask.distributed import Client, progress 

client = Client()
client
```

When I try to encode my data I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'MaterializedLayer' object has no attribute 'pack_annotations'
```

I encoded the data with the cluster closed and then tried to fit the model and I get the same error.

Comment: same problem when using AWS SageMaker. It was working okay till yesterday!

Comment: I am about to use a bigger instance and not go for a distributed approach, I don't see any other options on my end.

Comment: In my case, the largest possible instance was not sufficient. I ended up creating a crawler and connecting the data to an Athena database.

Comment: I was even deleting some columns, I managed to train the model, but It was not giving me any predictions, I will just go iddle... Do you mind telling me more about your approach?, I would like to give it a try but I have no idea 

Comment: Actually, my intention was to load a very large dataset and perform some SQL queries to filter some rows and export results, so in this case, I don't think my approach helps you. I suggest you try AWS EMR and create a cluster, then connect it to a SageMaker notebook. Let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Sagemaker Kernel most be python V3.8 which is compatible with dask distributed, as soon as I update the kernel to python 3.8. Works just fine.